# Python Dictionary Recursion

Tags: python, html, recursion, dictionary

How to figure this recursive function out?

First off I need to iterate a dictionary formatted as shown below:

```
{'style':'link',
 'size':'large',
 'parameters':{'id':'532',
               'section':'55'},
 'raw':'',
 'contains':{'style':'link',
             'size':'large',
             'parameters':{'id':'55',
                           'section':'32'},
             'raw':'',
             'contains':{...}
            }
}
```

This pattern continues until it reaches an empty dictionary `{}` in the *contains* field.

Here is the recursive function I've toyed around with:

```
def recursive(n):
    if 'contains' in [i.lower() for i in n.keys()]:
        val += recursive(n['contains'])
    else:
        return TagBuilder().buildTag(n)
```

The buildTag function builds a simple HTML tag based on the information provided in the dictionary.

here is the buildTag function:

```
def buildTag(self, _tag_dict):
    if isinstance(_tag_dict, dict):
        if set(self._valid_tag) == set(_tag_dict.keys()):
            return '<{0} {1}>{2}{3}</{0}>'.format(_tag_dict['style'], 
                self.parseAttribs(_tag_dict['parameters']), _tag_dict['contains'], _tag_dict['section'])
        else:
            return ''
    else:
        self.log.error('TypeError: invalid _tag_dict (%s), required (dict)' % type(_tag_dict).__name__)
        raise TypeError('invalid _tag_dict (%s), required (dict)' % type(_tag_dict).__name__)
```

What I need to be able to do is pass a dictionary like above, and create a set of nested HTML tags in the order which they are nested in the dictionary.
For example:

```
<tag_contains0><tag_contains1><tag_contains...></tag_contains...></tag_contains1</tag_contains0>
```

Comment: Ad what exactly *isn't working* here then? What, if anything, is your question about?

Comment: What was causing me trouble was the way the author of TagBuilder wrote the class. For some reason it was preventing me from creating a normal recursion method. So instead of recursing this dict in a crazy way, I rewrote the class to support my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may keep a list instead of recursion. When you meet something you need to descend into, you add that item to a list.

Something along these lines:

```
def not_recursive(n):
    val = ""
    unhandled_list = [n]
    while len(unhandled_list) > 0:
        # get the item to handle
        node = unhandled_list.pop(0)
        try:
            unhandled_list.append(node['contains'])
        except KeyError:
            val += TagBuilder().buildTag(n)
    return val
```

Note that the code above is not case-insensitive for simplicity (you have to tackle that separately). Also, it assumes that `node['contains']` is a new node, not a list of nodes. This is not a tree but a chain... (This may be a bug in the original code, and if it is actually a list of nodes, then just use `extend` instead of `append`.)

Also it might be that you want to add the tag string to `val` regardless of if a node has children or not. If this is the case, take the `val += ...` line away from the execption handling. (Replace it by `pass` and unindent the `val += ...` line.)

Comment: This helped me to answer my question. I ended up modifying the base `TagBuilder().buildTag()` to recurse on every `_tag_dict['contains']` _via_ `self.genTag(_tag_dict['_contains']) if '_contains' in _tag_dict else ''`. **Thanks for the help!**